# calling class inside another class

Tags: java

making project on network in below code i want mainframe class to be processed completely first after that SecondFrame class to be continued......

class SecondFrame 
    {

```
SecondFrame()
{



                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/net","root","simer");
    PreparedStatement ps=con1.prepareStatement("select * from record where email=?");
    ps.setString(1,c1);
    ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next())
    {
    b=rs.getDouble("balance");
    }
if(b>0)
{
                 long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("balance is"+b);
    System.out.println("connected");
d=f1.getText();
new mainframe(d);  \\main frame class
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    double totalTime = endTime - startTime;
    double et = totalTime/1000000000;
    System.out.println(et);
    double bal = b - (et*(.4));
    System.out.println(bal);
    PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement("UPDATE record SET balance=? where email=? ");
    ps1.setDouble(1,bal);
    ps1.setString(2,c1);
    ps1.executeUpdate();

    }
```

tried with the help of threads but not able to do it,in above the balance is deducted only for minute seconds which is even not recognized but want till the mainframe class is not closed balance to be deducted.....

Comment: Please **format your code** before posting it. If using an IDE there should be an autoformat button. Unformatted code is very hard for use to read - so many of us don't bother.

Comment: It's really not clear what your goal is here - this is not a clear and concise question with a minimal example. Don't post your complete code, but post the relevant parts that you don't know how to connect?

Answer (score 3):

Your "p" class should be a modal JDialog, not a JFrame. This way the calling code will be on hold, and the user cannot work on the main window until the dialog window has been handled, which I *think* is your desired behavior.

As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Also you should avoid using trivial variable names such as `b` or `s` unless they are being used for trivial purposes such as the index of a for loop. Instead use names that have some meaning so that your code becomes self-commenting.

Following these suggestions as well as following good code formatting practices will allow others (such as us!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, will allow your future self to better understand just what you were thinking 6 months ago when you wrote the code.

Also, you should avoid use of null layout as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.